# Qual é a diferença entre $('id') e $$('#id') no MooTools?

Tags: mootools

Para quem, como eu, está habituado com jQuery, a existência de duas funções para selecionar elementos no MooTools parece um pouco confusa.

Considerando que eu tenha um elemento qualquer como

```html
<div id="id">Conteúdo</div>
```

Qual é a diferença entre usar

```
$('id')
```

e

```
$$('#id')
```

para selecionar esse elemento? O retorno das duas funções é igual? A primeira seria mais rápida que a segunda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença neste caso é:

- `$` retorna *um* objeto
- `$$` retorna uma coleção (tipo array) com *um* objeto.

### O que são estes métodos`?

```
$('teste') === $$('#teste')[0] // true
$('teste') === document.getElementById('teste') // true
```

#### $ ou document.id

No MooTools `$('id')` é o correspondente a `document.getElementById()`.
O método aceita uma string que deve ser a ID de um elemento. Este método dá sempre um objecto. Se não encontrar nenhum retorna `null`.

Pode usar-se na forma `$('id')` ou ainda `document.id('id')` (mais seguro para não criar incompatibilidades com outras bibliotecas).

#### $$

`$$` é o método correspondente ao nativo `document.querySelectorAll`, com mais uns extras. Para browsers mais aintigos anteriores ao `.querySelectorAll` ele combina outros métodos nativos para procurar elementos no DOM. Este método retorna sempre uma array/coleção de Elementos e aceita seletores CSS. O motor de busca do MooTools (Slick) aceita mais alguns seletores como por exemplo `div !> ul`, que é um seletor inverso de `>`.

Se o `$$` (dollar duplo) não encontrar nenhum elemento do DOM ele retorna uma array vazia. Atênção que `[]` tem um valor booleano `true`, daí que usando $$ deve combinar-se com `.length` se queremos ter um booleano da busca.

### Performance

O método $ (ou document.id) é o mais simples dos dois. Porém como o $$ permite seletores CSS e o `$` é somente para IDs eles funcionam de maneira diferente. Em relação a performance estive a testar agora no IE, Firefox e Chrome e dão resultados diferentes. No IE vence o $ e nos outros o $$m, todos com diferenças a baixo dos 5%... concluo que são +/- semelhantes.

**Nota:** como o MooTools é uma biblioteca que estende o prototype pode usar-se também [métodos nativos combinados com MooTools](http://jsfiddle.net/2abh2h7j/) e aí fica bem mais rápido.

Teste $ vs $$: http://jsperf.com/seletoresdomootools

### Na prática:

Buscar o conteudo de `<div id="id">Conteúdo</div>`:

```
var conteudo = $('id').get('html');                         // dá-me "Conteúdo"
var conteudo = document.getElementById('id').get('html');   // dá-me "Conteúdo"
var conteudo = document.getElement('#id').get('html');      // dá-me "Conteúdo"
var conteudo = $$('#id').get('html');                       // dá-me ["Conteúdo"]
```

**Relacionado:**

No Mootools existe ainda um outro método: `document.getElement`, ele tem as funcionalidades de `$$` mas retorna um objeto como o `$`, o primeiro que encontrar.

Relacionado também: uma [resposta do Dimitar no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814865/2256325)

Comment: "retorna uma coleção (tipo array)" Presumo que devolva uma matriz preenchida com os objetos localizados, é isso?

Comment: `$('id') === $$('#id')[0]`? Ambos retornam um elemento estendido pela biblioteca?

Comment: @zuul é uma coleção com algumas propriedades como length e index/matriz mas não é uma Array.